# VBA how to capture a selected tab on userform?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to assign an integer to a variable based on which tab the user selects on the userform.  I have 3 tabs, so if the user selects the second tab, I want to assign that variable an integer of 2.

```
if tab2.Select = True then
    var1 = 2
end if
```

How do I write it in VBA code to realize a tab is being selected, and assign an integer to a variable as a result of that?

EDIT:  I have buttons on these pages via option buttons where I want to assign the user's selection to a variable as well. So if the user selects an option, would the following code be syntactically correct?

```
If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
    var2 = 1
ElseIf OptionButton2.Value = True Then
    var2 = 2
ElseIf OptionButton3.Value = True Then
    var2 = 3
End If
```

Comment: Have you tried ActiveSheet.Index?

Comment: What does that do? How would it work for a userform? NameOfUserform.Index?

Comment: oh sorry, I just re-read what you were wanting. You want the tab in the form, not the worksheet. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

If I had understood your question correctly I guess you are looking for a way to capture the page that is currently active on the userform and based on the selection copy some value to a variable. If yes, then you can achieve the same as follows :

```
Private Sub MultiPage1_Click(ByVal Index As Long)

Dim value_To_be_set as integer

    If Index = 0 Then

        value_To_be_set= 1

    ElseIf Index = 1 Then

        value_To_be_set= 2

    ElseIf Index = 2 Then

        value_To_be_set = 3

    End If

End Sub
```

Hope it helps